# two strings separated by blank being concatenated automatically

Tags: c

I just found something very interesting which was introduced by my typo. Here's a sample of very easy code script:

```
printf("A" "B");
```

The result would be

```
$> AB
```

Can someone explain how this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a part of the C standard, string literals  that are next to one another are concatenated:

For C (quoting C99, but C11 has something similar in 6.4.5p5):

> (C99, 6.4.5p5) "In translation phase 6, the multibyte character
>   sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and
>   identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a
>   single multibyte character sequence."

C++ has a similar standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behaviour and can be very useful when splitting a very long string constant over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is string concatenation, part of C standard. Any two or more consecutive string literals are combined into one.